# Agricultural data of Uttarakhand (1960-till date)

Tags: agriculture

Can anyone link me a page which mentions statistical data of Agriculture in Uttarakhand(India), I searched the internet for 4hrs now and still I got no result. Specifically the data around 1960s as it was the prime time of green revolution